# appendChild() is not a function

Tags: javascript, dom

cuando intenta agregar un elemento al dom de html me retorna que append child no es una función

```
function allCustomer(company_id){  
var request = endpoint + '?company_id=' + company_id
fetch(request)
.then(request => request.json())
.then(data => {
    for (d in data){
        var container_cards = document.getElementsByClassName("container_cards")
        var divCardCustomer = document.createElement('div');
        divCardCustomer.className = 'card_customer';
        container_cards.appendChild(divCardCustomer);
        console.log(data[d]);
    }
})}
```

Qusiera saber por que radica este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName` devuelve una lista de elementos, y en JavaScript, una lista no presenta el método `appendChild`, pero sí cada elemento de la misma.

Entiendo que deseas agregar un elemento hijo a cada elemento con la clase `container_cards`, y para ello debes recorrer tu lista de elementos, y llamar a `appendChild` por cada elemento, de esta forma:

```
for (var container_card of container_cards)
{
    container_card.appendChild(divCardCustomer);
}
```

---

Otra alternativa, sería emplear `document.querySelector`, de esta forma:

```
var container_cards = document.querySelector(".container_cards");

container_cards.appendChild(divCardCustomer);
```